# Combine DSL-like construstor call with anonymous class declaration

Tags: ceylon

Is it possible?
I tried something like this:

```
object foo extends Foo {
    constructorNamedArg = "qqq";
} {
    abstractMethod() => bar.baz();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/spec/html_single/#extendedclass), it is not possible, there can be only positional argument list.

Comment: How can one create a internal dsl in ceylon? Probabely using the Tree-syntax. Beyond that, syntactic improvements like a monadic for syntax would be very desirable in ceylon, e.g. for trampolining, since ceylon not even does tail recursion right. That requires to introduce new variables which is not possible using Tree-like syntax. What is the best way to work around that shortcomings in ceylon?

Answer (score 4):

I would not use inheritance for this. Instead I would define `Foo` as a concrete class:

```
class Foo(String constructorNamedArg, Baz abstractMethod()) {}
```

And now at the call site I would write:

```
Foo {
    constructorNamedArg = "qqq";
    abstractMethod() => bar.baz();
}
```

Or even:

```
Foo {
    constructorNamedArg = "qqq";
    function abstractMethod() { 
        return bar.baz(); 
    }
}
```

It's a common refactoring in Ceylon to go from abstract class with formal methods to concrete class parameterized by functions.

HTH